# Cannot complete pgadmin4 setup. Apache web server

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, apache2, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pgadmin

I've got problem with completing pgadmin4 installation thru `sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh` command.
During this process instalator does not recognizing that Apache is running and asks me if I want to start it:

`The Apache web server is not running. We can enable and start the web server for you to finish pgAdmin 4 installation. Continue (y/n)? y`

Then it just spits some errors:

```
Too few arguments.
Error enabling . Please check the systemd logs
Too few arguments.
Error starting . Please check the systemd logs
```

So far I havn't found where the logs are stored.

About my apache, I am quite sure that my server is running, because I can connect to it through browser, phpmyadmin is working properly, and `service apache2 status` returns  `* apache2 is running`. By my understanding `apache2` is just fancy word for `httpd` service, and there is no other service called simply `apache`.

PostgreSQL seems to work properly from command line, haven't tested if I can connect to it yet, but this shouldn't be the case right?

I am using

```
**PostgreSQL:** 12.5 (Ubuntu 12.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
**Ubuntu:** Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
**Server:** Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue for Debian 10 and Ubuntu 20.  The /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh script is using 'uname -a' which doesn't contain "Debian" identifier in the return string.  Updating this to read /proc/version will allow APACHE to be specified as the Debian variant of apache2.

Change:
UNAME=$(uname -a)

To:
UNAME=$(cat /proc/version)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Ubuntu running inside WSL 2. Managed to resolve it by modifying the `/usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh` script. I moved these lines outside of the conditional:

```
IS_DEBIAN=1
APACHE=apache2
```

This allowed the installation to progress beyond the `Too few arguments.` error. There was still an error however:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Error restarting apache2. Please check the systemd logs
```

I resolved this by running:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

After this I tried bringing up the admin page by visiting `http://127.0.0.1/pgadmin4` from the Windows host. This still didn't work, and had to connect using the Ubuntu machine's ip address (you can find it out via `ifconfig`) which finally allowed me to see the login page.